# Find the newly added elements of an Array of Objects with Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

Imagine we have two Arrays.

```
var a = [B, C, E];
var b = [A, B, C, D, E];
```

Array a is our default Array that we have saved locally.
Now the api we fetch from sends us the new version of this Array a called b.
How can I use lodash so I can get the difference of this two arrays so I get in this case
[A, D] returned ?

UPDATE:
I came up with my own solution it kinda worked, so only try this if the accepted answer does not work for some reason:

````
  const getObjectDiff = (newArr, oldArr) => {
    if (_.isEqual(newArr, oldArr)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      const checkLength = newArr.length;
      const checkerLength = oldArr.length;
      var indexes = [];
      var falseIndexes = [];
      var allIndexes = [];
      for (let i = 0; i <= checkerLength; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j <= checkLength - 1; j++) {
          allIndexes.push(i);
          if (_.isEqual(newArr[i], oldArr[j])) {
            indexes.push(i);
          } else {
            falseIndexes.push(i);
          }
        }
      }
      const falseUniqueIndexes = _.uniq(falseIndexes);
      return _.difference(falseUniqueIndexes, indexes);
    }
  };
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [_.differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith) along with the [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) to check deep equality between objects.

_.isEqual will perform a deep comparison between two objects to see if they are equivalent so we can use this to compare, say, objects that have been decoded from JSON.

This is a simple example, however, this will work with much more complex objects as long as they are equal (as determined by lodash)

```js
const apiResponseA = '[{"id":"B"},{"id":"C"},{"id":"E"}]';
const apiResponseB = '[{"id":"A"},{"id":"B"},{"id":"C"},{"id":"D"},{"id":"E"}]'

const a = JSON.parse(apiResponseA);
const b = JSON.parse(apiResponseB);

console.log("a:", apiResponseA)
console.log("b:", apiResponseB)

console.log("Difference:", JSON.stringify(_.differenceWith(b,a, _.isEqual)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you I wrote my own function, but now you came up with a better solution so bye bye my old function xD

Comment: Great,  I think the lodash approach should work well!

Answer (score 0):

I realize you asked specifically for a lodash solution, but I just want to mention that you could do this pretty simply without a 3rd party library - just use Array.prototype.filter and Array.prototype.includes, like this:

```js
var a = ['B', 'C', 'E'];
var b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

function getDifference(a, b) {
  return b.filter(letter => !a.includes(letter));
}

console.log(getDifference(a, b));
```

Comment: I dont know it this would work with my objects, though that is why I asked for lodash.